# Bash script to skip extraction of password protected archives

Tags: bash, zip, password-protection

I have a script, which performs mass extraction of specific zip and\or tar.gz archives in some folders using command:

```
unzip -o "$zip_path" -d "$destination_folder"
```

Unfortunately, when archive is password-protected, script stops and waiting for password input.

Is there any way to omit password entering stage to not interrupt script running?

P.S. There is no need to extract password-protected files. Only omit this archives.
Something like:

```
if "$zip_path" [ determine that archive is password-protected ]; then
echo "Password-protected"
elif "continue script execution"
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried the `−−ignore−failed−read` option for `tar` ?

Comment: It seems that all password-protected files are *.zip. Sorry for misguiding :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For zip files, you can specify a dummy (wrong) password with the `-P` flag.
For non-encrypted files it will be ignored,
for encrypted files you will get a warning and the file will be skipped. For example:

```
unzip -P x -o "$zip_path" -d "$destination_folder"
```

For tar files, encryption is not a standard feature, so I'm not sure you what you mean. You could try to redirect stdin to the script from `/dev/null` to make it fail to read and skip over to the next file:

```
tar -xvzf "$tgz_path" --directory "$destination_folder" < /dev/null
```

If this doesn't work, then you can try `expect`.

Comment: @VasiliyVegas I just tested now, and saw the problem. Fixed that in my answer for unzip. As for tar, I'm not sure what kind of encryption you mean.

Comment: yes, I've tested new script and see that all password-protected files are *.zip. Thanks for reply. I will edit question accordingly.