# Is there a way to check if a zip file is password protected?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

I'm writing a bash script which compresses (with encryption or without, depending on what the user chooses) and decompresses files using zip.
My problem is the decompressing part - when the user chooses a zip file to decompress (via zenity file selection), is there any way to check if the file is password protected in order to ask the user for the password (or if it isn't, just proceed and decompress the file)?

I didn't really try anything yet, as I've struggled to come up with any idea or find a solution on stack and other websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script to skip extraction of password protected archives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593758/608639). There are so many examples in so many languages on Stack Overflow you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if 7z l -slt file.zip | grep -q ZipCrypto; then
  echo "password protected / encrypted"
else
  echo "no password protection / not encrypted"
fi
```

See: [How to detect zip file encryption algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/126284)

Answer (score 0):

Also: In a DOS prompt, type "unzip myfile.zip" and if you get prompted for the password, it is protected.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found

To always try to set password.

If password not exist set `qwerty`

```
7z x -aou /tmp/archive.zip -pqwerty
```

If encrypted, there must be message
`encrypted archive! Wrong password`

For additional check
i recommend command that print technical info by 7z.

If password not exist set `qwerty`

```
7z l -slt /tmp/archive.zip -pqwerty
```

Output must  contain `Encrypted = +` or `encrypted archive! Wrong password`